# Amazon S3 - deleteObjects() - "guzzle" errors?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Here's the reduced but accurate code I'm working with.

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array('key'=>$ak,'secret'=>$sk));

foreach(range(1,10) as $i) $temp[] = array('Key'=>$i);

$result = $client->deleteObjects(array('Bucket'=>'bucket','Objects'=>$temp));

return $result;
```

Everything works, it deletes the objects as requested but it throws all of these errors from the phar file. Running this locally as you can see below.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 56: Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data [url] https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com?delete=' in phar://C:/wamp/www/bucket/local/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php on line 285`

`Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException: [curl] 56: Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data [url] https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com?delete= in phar://C:/wamp/www/bucket/local/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php on line 365`

`Aws\Common\Exception\TransferException: [curl] 56: Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data [url] https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com?delete= in phar://C:/wamp/www/bucket/local/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php on line 285`

Comment: I currently have the same problem, it usually is displayed when I try o get file list from bucket. Maybe problem with foareach()? I'm testing on Windows 7 with WAMP.

Comment: same here, win7 x64 and wamp.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem running WampServer on Windows 7 x64. Through dumb luck, I just stumbled across the solution.

Simply add `'scheme' => 'http'` to the factory config settings and it starts working!

Answer (score 1):

Little late I realize, but searches for this returned very little, hopefully this might help someone else.

I was also getting this error only when trying to deleteObjects, WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.4) 2.4, Windows 7 x64.  I think something is wrong with the Curl extension in this version of WAMP.  I installed WAMPSERVER (32BITS & PHP 5.4) 2.4 and had no issues with deleteObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to add

```
'curl.options' => array('CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION'=>'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0')
```

to S3Client::factory options.

No more mentioned curl errors, but now I sometimes receive Simple XML error: "Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document".

Comment: i added that, now i get the original errors and 3 additional simple xml __construct() errors :/ - needless to say everything is still functioning properly.. just more errors.